# Is it possible to start traversing SharePoint from a certain sub folder in Document Library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I want to know if it is possible to start traversing SharePoint artifacts from a certain subfolder or if traversing always starts from the root folder.

I need this for a method I'm writing so that in case of error the method does not start traversing from the beginning, but it continues where it left off when the error occurred.